# How can I renew parameters in iframe url upon click?

Tags: javascript

I have 3 buttons on a webpage. These buttons all open a modal. Each button link contains 2 added values that are passed as an extension of a iFrame url.

```
<h5 class="text-deepskyblue" data-course-id="trainingX" data-course-lang="english" data-target="#darkModalForm" data-toggle="modal" id="mylink" style="cursor: pointer;">GET BOOKLET</h5>
<h5 class="text-deepskyblue" data-course-id="trainingY" data-course-lang="french" data-target="#darkModalForm" data-toggle="modal" id="mylink" style="cursor: pointer;">GET BOOKLET</h5>
<h5 class="text-deepskyblue" data-course-id="trainingZ" data-course-lang="german" data-target="#darkModalForm" data-toggle="modal" id="mylink" style="cursor: pointer;">GET BOOKLET</h5>
```

i.e. iFrame src="https://www.example.com/?data-course-id=trainingY&data-course-lang=french"

Somehow when I click on the different links, the values of the first link I clicked on are added as an extension of the iFrame url. For the the other links this doesn't work. Instead it uses the values of the first link that was clicked on

Below the script I have been using.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe');
var link = document.getElementById('mylink');
iframe.src = iframe.src + (window.location.search ? window.location.search + '&' : '?') + (link && link.getAttribute('data-course-id') !== '' ? 'data-id=' + link.getAttribute('data-course-id') : '') + (link && link.getAttribute('data-course-lang') !== '' ? '&data-lang=' + link.getAttribute('data-course-lang') : '');
    console.log('################', iframe.src);
```

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to add to make sure the values are being refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you have given each of the h5 the same `id="mylink"` this means the first h5 matching that id is returned, which is your first h5. Without seeing the code that targets the relevant link, I can't help you target the link, but I am sure if you can make the id change and work it out from there.